# Where the contract code located physically and how it can be accessed?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, addresses, storage

After deployed where the contract code physically is located at? Storage or ROM of each node?
And how it can be accessed for execution? By contract address? Then, Does contract address act like a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum Smart Contracts are deployed as a transaction with code data along with it. Now, like any other transaction contract gets stored on Blockchain.

When a transaction results in smart contract code execution, EVM gets initiated by loading contract codes into EVMs' ROM and Contract Storage Data into EVMs' Storage.
[image]